# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' ... even though I can print it out

Tags: python, opencv, houghlinesp

I'm attempting to find vertical lines in a video. Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.
I am using background subtraction and then applying the Canny Edge Detection filter.
I've been able to apply the HoughLinesP method to a single image but need to expand this to a video.

I'm receiving this error when running a basic set of code (which I believe corresponds to the lines (30-33) below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test3.py", line 33, in <module>
print(hlines.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What's strange is that if Iadjust the code so that background subtraction is *not* applied (comment line 26 and change line 28 so that it's referring to 'frame' instead of 'img_sub'), everything works just fine.  What am I missing?
I can output a background subtracted video stream just fine and it works as expected.
I can output/ print(hlines) just fine.
Example terminal output of 'hlines'

```
[[470 109 470 109]]

[[337 259 337 259]]

[[330 267 330 267]]

[[338 324 338 324]]

[[338 289 338 289]]]
```

But, as soon as I try to use the hlines.shape attribute, things go wonky.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils 

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf) #to print entire array, no truncation

LOWER_BOUND = 55   #cv2.threshold()
UPPER_BOUND = 255  #cv2.threshold()

CANNY_LOWER_BOUND = 10  #cv2.Canny()
CANNY_UPPER_BOUND = 250 #cv2.Canny()

MIN_LINE_LENGTH = 2  #HoughLinesP()
MAX_LINE_GAP = 100     #HoughLinesP() 
HOUGH_THETA = np.pi/180 #HoughLinesP() angle resolution of the accumulator, radians
HOUGH_THRESHOLD = 25 #HoughLinesP() 
HOUGH_RHO = 1         #HoughLinesP() rho, Distance resolution of the accumulator, pixels

#background subtraction parameter
bkgnd = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
camera =cv2.VideoCapture('/home/odroid/Desktop/python_scripts/test/test_images/Edited_Foam_Dispense_Short.mp4')

while(True):
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

img_sub = bkgnd.apply(frame)#, learningRate = 0.001)

canny_threshold = cv2.Canny(img_sub, CANNY_LOWER_BOUND, CANNY_UPPER_BOUND)  

hlines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny_threshold, HOUGH_RHO, HOUGH_THETA, MIN_LINE_LENGTH, MAX_LINE_GAP)

print(hlines)
print(hlines.shape)

#a,b,c = hlines.shape

#for k in range(a):
    #print(hlines.shape)
    #break
    #cv2.line(frame, (hlines[k][0][0], hlines[k][0][1]), (hlines[k][0][2], hlines[k][0][3]), (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
#   print("getting hlines")
#   break

cv2.imshow('canny_threshold', canny_threshold)
cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:
@ivan_pozdeev pointed me to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452491/opencv-python-houghlinesp-strange-results)

It does look like it applies. But, while trying to follow their solution, I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 37, in 
    for l in hlines:
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

This is the modified code snippet:

```
hlines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny_threshold, HOUGH_RHO, HOUGH_THETA, MIN_LINE_LENGTH, MAX_LINE_GAP)

for l in hlines:
    leftx, boty, rightx, topy = l[0]
    line = Line((leftx, boty), (rightx, topy)) 
    line.draw(frame, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Now, this would kind of makes sense to me if I didn't have data ... but I *do* have data being returned in hlines. I can print it out using a print(hlines) statement.  However, it has a different format than OpenCV 2.4... But, now it has me wondering why it worked in the other question...

EDIT2:
Ah ha!  Making progress.  Here's the output of the script (print(hlines)) if I only loop it twice ... ie, when run_once = 0 while(run_once<=1) ... run_once = 1+ run_once at the end

```
None
[[[690 419 693 419]]

[[672 419 679 419]]

[[696 417 701 417]]

[[713 419 714 419]]

[[504 418 504 418]]

[[688 419 688 419]]

[[672 417 679 417]]

[[510 419 511 419]]

[[693 418 693 417]]

[[688 417 688 417]]

[[692 417 692 417]]

[[696 419 699 419]]

[[713 417 714 417]]

[[686 419 686 419]]

[[622 417 622 417]]

[[690 417 690 417]]

[[506 417 506 417]]

[[622 419 623 419]]

[[505 419 505 419]]

[[686 417 687 417]]

[[506 419 506 419]]

[[700 419 701 418]]

[[509 418 509 418]]

[[623 417 623 417]]

[[510 417 511 417]]

[[712 418 712 418]]

[[685 418 685 418]]

[[689 417 689 417]]

[[689 419 689 419]]

[[671 418 671 418]]

[[691 417 691 417]]]
```

So it looks like the first row of hlines is "None". Which explains the error, I think.  However, now I need to figure out how to add an "empty row" to hlines ....

Comment: you `while True` statement is not indented.

Comment: `hlines` is not an array. The `shape` property can be used only with arrays.

Comment: why would doing back ground subtraction change this from an array to... not an array?  
that doesn't make sense in my head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencv python HoughLinesP strange results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452491/opencv-python-houghlinesp-strange-results)

Comment: The error means that `lines` is `None`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev : I've looked through the linked question. Thank you. It does look like it applies but I'm getting an odd error stating that I can't iterate over a value ... I'll update above.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link posted above by @ivan_pozdeev and checking for a return type of None fixed the issue.
The HoughLinesP function was returning an empty array on the first frame (returning "None"). This caused errors down the line. Adding in a check for that fixed the issue.

```
if hlines is None: #in case HoughLinesP fails to return a set of lines
        #make sure that this is the right shape [[ ]] and ***not*** []
        hlines = [[0,0,0,0]]
    else:
        for l in hlines:
            leftx, boty, rightx, topy = l[0]
            cv2.line(frame, (leftx, boty), (rightx, topy), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: All that leaves is find out why it's `None`. This possibility is not mentioned in in the documentation. I checked [its source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/26be2402a3ad6c9eacf7ba7ab2dfb111206fffbb/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L870) and didn't find any immediately apparent cases.

Comment: double-checked the link - it's fine. Maybe https://github.com is blocked in your country or something.

Comment: might be at work ... i'll fiddle with it. which source were you checking? the HoughLinesP?